# Do eigenvalues and singular values of a symmetric, positive definite random matrix coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I know the eigenvalues and singular values are the same for symmetric, positive definite matrices (e.g., see [Why do positive definite symmetric matrices have the same singular values as eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867652/why-do-positive-definite-symmetric-matrices-have-the-same-singular-values-as-eig)). Does this still hold for a symmetric, positive definite random matrices?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the random modifer matter?

Comment: It holds. The singular values will be random variables as well as the unitary matrix you use for writing down the singular value decomposition.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Some properties change when going from deterministic to random and so I'm not sure whether that's my case...

Comment: @GGG Thanks. That's what I thought as well, yet did not find any technical documents for that... Do you have any to recommend?

Comment: what do you want to know? the distribution of singular values/eigenvalues? My knowlegde on random matrices mostly comes from "An Introduction to Random Matrices" (Anderson, Guionnet, Zeitouni). You may also take a look at Terence Tao's blog.

Comment: @GGG I'll see if there are what I need. Thanks a lot!