# Singular values vs eigenvalues for positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is positive definite, why are singular values of $A$ the same as eigenvalues of $A$ ?

Here's an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867652/why-do-positive-definite-symmetric-matrices-have-the-same-singular-values-as-eig) (the accepted one).

But I feel like this answer only shows that "if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then it is also a singular value of $A$".

How to show that if $\sigma$ is a singular value of $A$, then it is also an eigenvalue of $A$?

That is, starting from $A^T A v = \sigma^2 v$ $\implies $ $A^2 v = \sigma^2 v$.

How does the last expression imply $Av = \sigma v$?

I know $Av = \sigma v$ $\implies $ $A^2 v = \sigma^2 v$ but not so sure about the reverse implication?

Comment: You're right. But a positive matrix is necessarily symmetric (or hermitian).

Answer (score 2):

Let $B=A^2$, $\beta=\sigma^2$ to simplify notation a bit. So you have $Bv=\beta v$. Apply $B$ again, you get $B^2v=\beta^2v$. Again, and again, etc., and you get $B^nv=\beta^nv$ for all $n$. Take linear combinations of this, and you get 
$$
p(B)v=p(\beta)v
$$
for any polynomial $B$. Now choose $p$ to be a polynomial such that $p(\sigma_j^2)=\sigma_j$ for all $j$. Then $p(B)$ is the unique positive square root of $B$, namely $A$. So each $\sigma_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: I need some clarification. Suppose $A^T A = A^2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then there are $n$ singular values, including zero ones. So how do we know there exists a polynomial $p$ that satisfies $p(\sigma_i^2) = \sigma_i$ for all $i = 1, ..., n$? Is there a theorem like "the polynomial $p$ need to be of degree $n$" or something? Can you elaborate on this part?

Comment: $B$ is positive definite so has a unique positive definite square root. Your answer also implies the following: given $B v_i = \sigma_i^2 v_i$ for all $i=1, ..., n$, any matrix $C$ which satisfies $C v_i = \sigma_i v_i$ is the square root of $B$. Is that a theorem in linear algebra also?

Comment: Given $n$ pairs of number $(x_j,y_j)$, you can always construct a degree $n$ polynomial $p$ with $p(x_j)=y_j$; this can be done explicitly (look "Lagrange Interpolation"). As for your second question, the answer is trivially yer, if $\{v_j\}$ are a basis made out of eigenvectors: $C^2$ agrees with $B$ on a basis, so $C^2=B$.