# Eigenvalues and Singular Values of Negative Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

If $A$ is positive definite ($A^T=A$ and $\lambda_i(A)>0$) then the singular values $\sigma_i(A)$ coincide with the eigenvalues $\lambda_i(A)$. This fact was proved in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867652/why-do-positive-definite-symmetric-matrices-have-the-same-singular-values-as-eig), and it made me curious as to whether the same (or something similar) happens when $A$ is negative definite $(A^T=A$ and $\lambda_i(A)<0$).

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is negative definite, then $B=-A$ is definite positive and $BB^T = AA^T$. The [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of $B$ are therefore equal to the one of $A$ and also to the eigenvalues of $A$ according to the result you mention.

While the eigenvalues of $B$ are the opposite of the one of $A$.

Finally, the singular values of $A$ are the opposite of its eigenvalues. This is just saying that $\sqrt{\vert \lambda \vert} = \sqrt{- \lambda}$ for $\lambda \le 0$.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{|\lambda|}=-\lambda$? Are you missing a '$^2$' or am I missing something?

Comment: There is indeed a typo! I meant $\sqrt{\vert \lambda \vert} = \sqrt{- \lambda}$ for $\lambda \le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Singular values are always nonnegative, but the eigenvalues of a negative definite matrix are always negative. So, the singular values cannot possibly be equal to the eigenvalues in this case.

However, in general, when $A$ is normal (this includes the case where $A$ is negative definite), its singular values are precisely the moduli of its eigenvalues, i.e. $\sigma_k(A)=|\lambda_(A)|$. Let $\lambda_1(A),\ldots,\lambda_n(A)$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ and let $\lambda_k(A)=|\lambda_k(A)|e^{i\theta_k}$ for each $k$. Since $A$ is normal, it can be unitarily diagonalised as $A=U\Lambda U^\ast$. Therefore $A=(UD)|\Lambda|U^\ast$ is a singular value decomposition of $A$, where $|\Lambda|=\operatorname{diag}(|\lambda_1(A)|,\ldots,|\lambda_n(A)|)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\ldots,e^{i\theta_n})$. It follows that the singular values of $A$ are $|\lambda_1(A)|,\ldots,|\lambda_n(A)|$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $\sigma_i(A)=\sqrt{\lambda_i(A^TA)}$. If $A=A^T$ then $\sigma_i(A)=\sqrt{\lambda_i(A^2)}$. By eigendecomposition $A=U\Sigma U^T$ we see that $A^2=U\Sigma^2 U^T$ so $\lambda_i(A^2)=\lambda_i(A)^2$. We conclude that $\sigma_i(A)=\sqrt{\lambda_i(A)^2}=|\lambda_i(A)|$. This is true for symmetric matrices in general, we do not need to assume $A$ is positive or negative definite.

Comment: No, This gives $\sigma_i = |\lambda_i|$. Of course some eigenvalues are not positive if $A$ is not positive.

Comment: Thanks, updated question to fix this.